# How can I input endmark?

Tags: theorems, ntheorem

This is my code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[thmmarks,standard,thref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\square}}
\newtheorem{sol}{Soluttion}

\begin{document}
\begin{sol}
This is an exercise
\end{sol}


\begin{sol}
This is an exercise
\begin{equation}
x^2 - 2(m+1)x - m^2 - 1 = 0.
\end{equation}
\end{sol}
\end{document}
```

I input endmark, but after `\begin{equation}`
`\end{equation}`
I can not receive endmark.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in Gonzalo’s edit. You can also highlight the code and click the “code” button (with “{}” on it).

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: I do get both endmarks with your example code. Are you using outdated package(s)?

Comment: That's odd. The example on page 18 of the [ntheorem manual](http://user.informatik.uni-goettingen.de/~may/Ntheorem/ntheorem.pdf) leads me to believe that this should work. It seems that one is also supposed to pass the `amsmath` option to ntheorem after amsmath is loaded, but this does not fix things on my end.

Comment: The first run of the document won't show the endamrk at the `equation` environment; after the second run, the endmark will be placed. Also notice that you should load `ntheorem` including the `amsmath` option: `\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks,standard,thref]{ntheorem}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what you want is already provided by the `proof` environment of `amsthm`.

try the following (simplified from your example):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb} % loads amsfonts automatically

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}[Solution]
This is an exercise
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[Solution]
This is an exercise
\begin{equation}
x^2 - 2(m+1)x - m^2 - 1 = 0.
\qedhere
\end{equation}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

the `proof` heading can be changed to "Solution" by adding the code

```
\renewcommand{\proofname}{Solution}
```

in the preamble.

only the `proof` environment is set up to recognize `\qedhere`.  adding this facility to theorem-class environments is on the ams list of requests for consideration, but isn't likely to be looked at for a while.

Comment: What's the definition of "a while"?:)

Comment: @YiannisLazarides -- no earlier than next year.  (the department priority list is rather full, and this isn't at the top.)

Comment: @YiannisLazarides -- so am i ...

Comment: Thank you very much. But, i i use \usepackage[thmmarks,standard,thref]{ntheorem}
how must i do? Please help me.

Comment: @toandhsp [Gonzalo's comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57771/how-can-i-input-endmark#comment121535_57771) appears to solve the problem on my end. Just compile twice. [Admittedly, this is not a satisfying solution.]